# Excel Macro Radiobuttons dependent on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a cell `A1` which is filled with a dollar value eg. `20000` based on a vlookup. Depending on the value which is found I want 1 of 4 radiobuttons to be selected.

```
0-40K  40-150K  150-300K  >300K
```

I would prefer not to create a macro (for simplicity) and also it needs to update as the cell A1 is updated.

Any help is much appreciated!

Newest code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D8")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("D8").Value
            Case 0 To 39999
                revenue1.Value = True
            Case 40000 To 149999
                revenue2.Value = True
            Case 150000 To 299999
                revenue3.Value = True
            Case Else
                revenue4.Value = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Also all radio buttons are in the same sheet. apologies for the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without macros but it only works one-way. The key is to use Form Controls, not ActiveX controls. Insert however many `Option Button (Form Control)` objects you want. Right-click on one and then click on "Format Control". In the "Control" tab, choose a linked cell. Now the value of that cell will determine which radio button is selected. If you put in 4 radios, then the cell value will be 1, 2, 3, or 4. 
[image: Step 1][image: Step 2]

Now comes the tough part, though. You can set that cell to have a formula value based on the value in `A1` but manually selecting a radio button will overwrite that formula. Unless this is a template for something where the user saves a new copy of the master every time, that's probably not OK. You would still need a short macro to rewrite the formula every time cell `A1` changes which defeats the entire purpose. In that case, you would be better off setting the radio buttons with VBA directly and that's better done with ActiveX controls.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("A1").Value
            Case 0 To 39999
                OptionButton1.Value = True
            Case 40000 To 149999
                OptionButton2.Value = True
            Case 150000 To 299999
                OptionButton3.Value = True
            Case Else
                OptionButton4.Value = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It is that logic which I needed. I still haven't gotten it working though, not sure that the radiobuttons pick up the action correctly.

I renamed them and replaced in code as: revenue1.Value = True, revenue2.. etc. 

when i switch sheets (which i assume is the trigger) nothing seems to happen.

How can i trigger this to run to see that it works from a user perspective? 

Thanks again for the help so far!!

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` fires when a cell value / formula on the worksheet changes. The `If Not Intersect` line limits the nested code to only running when cell `A1` changes instead of running whenever *any* cell changes. To see it work, change the value of `A1`. (Also, make sure the code is inside the relevant worksheet and not just in a module.)

Comment: embedding it to the relevant worksheet was my mistake there, thanks!

The line: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Throws a "Variable not Defined" error. I am not sure which part of this line needs definition?

Thanks again!

Comment: That's probably because the `Option Explicit` statement requires all your objects and variables to be well-defined and accurate. Most likely, you added a variable somewhere or the objects aren't named exactly right. Also, my code assumes that the radio buttons are in the same worksheet as `A1` that's changing. If they're not, we need to more explicit in the code. It would have to be something like `Sheet1.revenue1` instead of just `revenue1`. Can you add your code to the original post?

Comment: I've had to run it without the If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D8")) Is Nothing Then... then everything works perfectly.. I realize this could lead to errors not being handled. But its the only way I found it to work.

Comment: Your change shouldn't cause any errors. The only difference is that how the code will run every time any cell in the worksheet is changed instead of only when `A1` is changed. I find it very curious, indeed, because it seems like it's saying that `Target` is not defined but it's a parameter for the event so it *should* be defined.